# How to re-render a react component based on function call?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a list from REST API call and re-render it whenever I add, delete or update a new item.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1',
      );
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);


  const handleClick = () => {
    fetchData();
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Go</button>
  );
}
export default App;
```

When the component loads it execute `useEffect` method but it doesn't work when I click on "Go" button.
Is there a way to execute my REST API call and refresh my list of objects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a state property and toggle it in onClick handler. Then use this property in a dependency array of the useEffect.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [refetch, setRefetch] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1',
      );
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [refetch]);


  const handleClick = () => {
    setRefetch(!refetch);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Go</button>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `data` variable to your array which keeps a check of things changing in the `useEffect` method. It should re-render whenever the `data` variable changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1',
      );
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData, data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first you are using the wrong endpoint. Please test your endpoint and it works with an id. And you don't need useEffect to load data by click event.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const fetchData = async () => {
  const result = await axios("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/items/1");
  return result.data;
};

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    const x = await fetchData();
    setData(x);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go</button>
      {data && data.id}
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can check it from this link https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-bhaskara-wtl1r